# Enum parameter in EL expression on Websphere

Tags: jsf, enums, websphere, el

In a JSF/facelet page, I'm trying to call a method with an enum value as a parameter, like this:

```
<f:viewAction action="#{myController.myMethod('MY_ENUM_VALUE')}" />
```

The code is working correctly using Tomcat but when trying with Websphere, this is not working anymore and I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /myPage.xhtml @16,24 action="#{myController.myMethod('MY_ENUM_VALUE')}": Method not found: com.example.MyController@807f4c26.myMethod(java.lang.String)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:109)
```

I'm wondering if there is a simple solution (configuration in Websphere?) or if I should integrate a different EL implementation in my WAR to override the one of Websphere. Any other suggestion is also welcome.

Additional information:

- Websphere 8.5, using Mojarra 2.2.5 implementation (override implementation of Websphere, using PARENT_LAST mode)
- Using Spring (with the `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` configured in `faces-config.xml`)
- I'm not packaging any special EL implementation in the EAR/WAR.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat does not provide a JSF implementation so you are free to provide any version compatible with the servler/JSP version provided by your Tomcat server.

However, [WebSphere AS 8.5 is a full Java EE 6](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_prog_model_support.html) application server that integrates JSF into the container.

Bundling libraries into a WAR that are contained in the server does not automatically override the server libraries. Java defaults to a parent-first class loading model. Some of the configuration information available in arbitrary enterprise libraries may not make sense to the container and result in undefined behavior. Additionally, deployment descriptors can specify the loading of WAR-specific libraries that are not necessarily compatible with the container.

Some containers (WebSphere among them) support parent-last class loading. This can result in so much weird behavior it should generally be avoided.

As far as I am aware there is only [one documented way to support a `com.sun.faces...` JSF implementation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/ihs/tihs_startadmserv.html) and I suspect in is only temporarily there to support WAS 7 binary JSF app WAR files.

---

So, it is possible that you are not really overriding the platform implementation but are triggering some undefined behavior by bundling JSF libraries in the WAR file.

*It is possible I've missed something about what you are doing; if so, provide more details.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is absolutely valid and interesting answer. Unfortunately I forgot to mention, I'm already using the PARENT_LAST mode in Websphere and I'm sure that Mojarra is used.

Comment: Since JSF 1.2, JSPs and JSF have shared a [unified EL implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language). Though it does not appear in the stack trace I believe JSF will delegate to the platform [javax.el](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/package-summary.html) EL 2.2 implementation. When I tried to evaluate a similar expression to yours I got the same result on the JSF 2.1 implementation built into WAS 8.5.5. I would conclude that this is a platform limitation/bug.